# How more effectively solve problems with "FindInstance" when number of variables is significantly greater then number of equations

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, symbolic, nonlinear

Can you help me with solving the following problem:

There are 16 variables and 3 equations (constraints) on them; is it possible to effectively solve such problems in Mathematica? What is more, there should be a constraint on `Abs[(x0 + I y0)]^2+Abs[(v0 + I w0)]^2==1` (for other variables similarly).

```
b0 = {{1}, {0}};
b1 = {{0}, {1}};
```

these are 4 qubits

```
psi[0] = (x0 + I y0) b0 + (v0 + I w0) b1;
psi[1] = (x1 + I y1) b0 + (v1 + I w1) b1;
psi[2] = (x2 + I y2) b0 + (v2 + I w2) b1;
psi[3] = (x3 + I y3) b0 + (v3 + I w3) b1;
```

Example steps for psi[0]

1. we define a density matrix in the following way:

   `ro[0] = Refine[psi[0].ConjugateTranspose[psi[0]], {x0, y0, v0, w0} > 0]`
2. this is an element of the POVM, 2 times 2 matrix

   `R[0] = 1/2ro[0];`
3. sum of these matrices should give an identity matrix

   `sum = Sum[R[i], {i, 0, 3}]`

The above requirement allows us to write the following equations(?)

Do you know is it possible to solve such equations with NSolve or find some solutions with FindInstance?

```
FindInstance[-2 + x0^2 + x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + y0^2 + y1^2 + y2^2 + 
     y3^2 == 0 && v0 x0 + v1 x1 + v2 x2 + v3 x3 + w0 y0 + w1 y1 + w2 y2 + w3 y3 == 
    0 && w0 x0 + w1 x1 + w2 x2 + w3 x3 - v0 y0 - v1 y1 - v2 y2 - 
     v3 y3 == 0, {x0, y0, v0, w0, x1, y1, v1, w1, x2, y2, v2, w2, x3, 
   y3, v3, w3}, Reals, 1] // N
```

I also tried to solve this problem with different parameterization of states:

`psi[0] = Cos[θ0/2] b0 + Exp[I*ϕ0] Sin[θ0/2] b1;`

Similar steps allow for deriving the following set of equations

```
FindInstance[
  Cos[θ0] + Cos[θ1] + Cos[θ2] + Cos[θ3] ==
     0 && Cos[ϕ0] Sin[θ0] + Cos[ϕ1] Sin[θ1] + 
     Cos[ϕ2] Sin[θ2] + Cos[ϕ3] Sin[θ3] == 0 &&
    Sin[θ0] Sin[ϕ0] + Sin[θ1] Sin[ϕ1] + 
     Sin[θ2] Sin[ϕ2] + Sin[θ3] Sin[ϕ3] == 
    0, {θ0, θ1, θ2, θ3, ϕ0, ϕ1, ϕ2, ϕ3}, Reals, 1] // N
```

This approach doesn't allow me to find anything. Maybe you know how one can solve such problems more effectively?

Thanks for any help with this.
J.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: FindInstance tries to find exact (algebraic) roots. Do you look for exact solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same method by @bbgodfrey.

At first we deal with the second and third equations since they are the homogeneous equation.(Furthormore we can `Reduce` it )

Here we also use some compact notations.

```
x = {x0, x1, x2, x3};
y = {y0, y1, y2, y3};
v = {v0, v1, v2, v3};
w = {w0, w1, w2, w3};
vars = Flatten[{x, y, v, w}];
ins = FindInstance[{v . x + w . y == 0, w . x - v . y == 0, 
    And @@ UnequalTo[0] /@ vars}, vars, Reals,1];
norm = x . x + y . y /. ins[[1]];
{x, y, v, w} = Sqrt[2/norm]*{x, y, v, w} /. ins[[1]];
sol = Thread[vars -> Flatten[{x, y, v, w}]]
-2 + x0^2 + x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + y0^2 + y1^2 + y2^2 + y3^2 == 0 && 
  v0 x0 + v1 x1 + v2 x2 + v3 x3 + w0 y0 + w1 y1 + w2 y2 + w3 y3 == 0 &&
   w0 x0 + w1 x1 + w2 x2 + w3 x3 - v0 y0 - v1 y1 - v2 y2 - v3 y3 == 
   0 /. sol
```

> `{x0 -> -Sqrt[(2/11)], x1 -> -Sqrt[(2/11)], x2 -> -2 Sqrt[2/11],  x3 -> -Sqrt[(2/11)], y0 -> -Sqrt[(2/11)], y1 -> -Sqrt[(2/11)],  y2 -> -Sqrt[(2/11)], y3 -> -Sqrt[(2/11)], v0 -> -Sqrt[(2/11)],  v1 -> -Sqrt[(2/11)], v2 -> -Sqrt[(2/11)], v3 -> -Sqrt[(2/11)],  w0 -> -Sqrt[(2/11)], w1 -> -Sqrt[(2/11)], w2 -> -9 Sqrt[2/11],  w3 -> 16 Sqrt[2/11]}`

Answer (score 5):

If number of variables is greater than the number of equations on might look for a minimum solution (similar to  `PseudoInverse` for linear problems):

Similar to @Akku14's clever answer try

```
mini = NMinimize[{    vars1 . vars1, Thread[eqs1 == 0]}, vars1 ]
    (*{2., {x0 -> 0.476697, y0 -> -0.857636, v0 -> -1.03538*10^-30, 
  w0 -> -1.82424*10^-30, x1 -> 0.293517, y1 -> -0.446633, 
  v1 -> 5.42342*10^-31, w1 -> 9.86076*10^-32, x2 -> 0.68577, 
  y2 -> -0.295276, v2 -> 5.42342*10^-31, w2 -> 6.40949*10^-31, 
  x3 -> -0.0942965, y3 -> -0.430379, v3 -> 4.19082*10^-31, 
  w3 -> -2.46519*10^-31}}*)
```

Comment: Very clever (+1). Then FindInstance can easily work with the remaining equation  `eqs1 /. Thread[
  Evaluate[Cases[mini[[2]] // Chop, Rule[aa_, 0] -> aa]] -> 0] `

Answer (score 4):

You can use NMinimize.

```
vars1 = {x0, y0, v0, w0, x1, y1, v1, w1, x2, y2, v2, w2, x3, y3, v3, 
         w3};
(eqs1 = Subtract @@@ 
 List @@ (-2 + x0^2 + x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + y0^2 + y1^2 + y2^2 + 
     y3^2 == 0 && 
   v0 x0 + v1 x1 + v2 x2 + v3 x3 + w0 y0 + w1 y1 + w2 y2 + 
     w3 y3 == 0 && 
   w0 x0 + w1 x1 + w2 x2 + w3 x3 - v0 y0 - v1 y1 - v2 y2 - 
     v3 y3 == 0));

nmin1 = NMinimize[{eqs1.eqs1, Thread[eqs1 == 0]}, vars1, 
           WorkingPrecision -> 25]

(*   {0, {x0 -> -0.2688698621225149789707399, 
y0 -> -0.6778829684493148842221356, 
v0 -> -0.4599201839580140286276144, 
w0 -> -0.7244698615595609677369415, 
x1 -> 0.7764510656415366048951560, 
y1 -> -0.4594336779699087692804516, 
v1 -> -0.1147213848446481707078258, 
w1 -> -0.1394270088263146193311412, 
x2 -> -0.004129737804174234957776942, 
y2 -> 0.1133188085181842516758908, 
v2 -> 0.4228333046093424543366667, 
w2 -> 0.4599659401886634735379034, 
x3 -> 0.7759590155226886589669734, 
y3 -> -0.1981350944948345426075089, 
v3 -> -0.6731961155868888303000809, 
w3 -> 0.5942934315955578978673677}}   *)

eqs1 /. nmin1[[2]]

(*   {0.*10^-25, 0.*10^-25, 0.*10^-25}   *)
```

With different methods or starting vaues for vars, you get other solutions.

Comment: Nice answer. Sometimes one might be interested in a minimum  solution `NMinimize[{ vars1 . vars1, Thread[eqs1 == 0]}, vars1, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 25]`

Answer (score 3):

`FindInstance` appears to begin guesses with integer values of `1` or `0`.  As a result, the first of the three equations yields complex solutions for the remaining variables.  So, replace `2` by `200` in the first equation and then renormalize the result

```
FindInstance[-200 + x0^2 + x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + y0^2 + y1^2 + y2^2 + y3^2 == 0 
    && v0 x0 + v1 x1 + v2 x2 + v3 x3 + w0 y0 + w1 y1 + w2 y2 + w3 y3 == 0 
    && w0 x0 + w1 x1 + w2 x2 + w3 x3 - v0 y0 - v1 y1 - v2 y2 - v3 y3 == 0, 
    {x0, y0, v0, w0, x1, y1, v1, w1, x2, y2, v2, w2, x3,y3, v3, w3}] /. 
    Rule[a_, b_] -> Rule[a, b/10]

(* {x0 -> -(1/10), y0 -> -(1/10), v0 -> 1/10, w0 -> 1/10, x1 -> 1/10, 
    y1 -> 0, v1 -> 0, w1 -> 1/10, x2 -> 1/10, y2 -> 1/30 (-2 - 4 Sqrt[73]), 
    v2 -> 0, w2 -> -(1/10), x3 -> 1/20 (-2 + 1/3 (2 + 4 Sqrt[73])), 
    y3 -> 1/20 (2 + 1/3 (-2 - 4 Sqrt[73])), v3 -> -(1/10), w3 -> 1/10} *)
```

Test the correctness by

```
Simplify[List @@ (-2 + x0^2 + x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + y0^2 + y1^2 + y2^2 + y3^2 == 0 
    && v0 x0 + v1 x1 + v2 x2 + v3 x3 + w0 y0 + w1 y1 + w2 y2 + w3 y3 == 0 
    && w0 x0 + w1 x1 + w2 x2 + w3 x3 - v0 y0 - v1 y1 - v2 y2 - v3 y3 == 0) /. %]

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Obtain other solutions by selecting different values of the `FindInstance` option, `RandomSeeding`.